# Apache Ignite poor performance compared to Redis

Tags: ignite

I did a simplistic benchmark of apache ignite recently and found that when I made use of the ignite client across 50 threads, the performance degraded tremendously.  The benchmark pits Redis against Ignite and Jedis, the Redis java client, seems to do much better in the threaded scenario since it keeps multiple clients in a pool rather than using one client among multiple threads.

My question is, am I seeing the degraded performance as a result of what i've just articulated, or is this actually expected and the client isn't the bottleneck?

Here were my results. The local host is a mac pro with 12 2.7GHz cores and 64gb of ram.  The remote host was an AWS m4.4xlarge.

```
Benchmark Results

*50 - 118kb Audio File Streamed and Read Simultaneously from One Node in 4096 byte chunks*

Redis

*Notes:*
I used a 50ms polling interval to check for updates to the cache.

*Results:*
Local:
- Total Time to stream and read 50 audio files: 226ms.
- average complete read and write: 125ms
- average time to first byte read: 26ms
- average read time per runner: 103ms
- average write time per runner: 71ms
- p99 time to first byte: 59ms
- p90 time to first byte: 57ms
- p50 time to first byte: 6ms

Remote (Over SSH | Seattle → IAD):
- Total Time to stream and read 50 audio files: 1405ms.
- average complete read and write: 1298ms
- average time to first byte read: 81ms
- average read time per runner: 1277ms
- average write time per runner: 1238ms
- p99 time to first byte: 148ms
- p90 time to first byte: 126ms
- p50 time to first byte: 84ms

Remote (Through VIP | Seattle → IAD):
- Total Time to stream and read 50 audio files: 2035ms.
- average complete read and write: 1245ms
- average time to first byte read: 67ms
- average read time per runner: 1226ms
- average write time per runner: 1034ms
- p99 time to first byte: 161ms
- p90 time to first byte: 87ms
- p50 time to first byte: 74ms


Ignite

*Notes:*
I have a feeling these numbers are artificially inflated.  I think the client is not well built for extreme parallelism.  I believe it's doing quite a bit of locking.  I think if you were to have many nodes doing the same amount of work, the numbers might be better.  This would require more in depth benchmarking.  This is 50 caches, one cache group.

*Results:*
Local:
- Total Time to stream and read 50 audio files: 327ms.
- average complete read and write: 321ms
- average time to first byte read: 184ms
- average read time per runner: 225ms
- average write time per runner: 35ms
- p99 time to first byte: 212ms
- p90 time to first byte: 197ms
- p50 time to first byte: 191ms

Remote (Over SSH | Seattle → IAD):
- Total Time to stream and read 50 audio files: 5148ms.
- average complete read and write: 4483ms
- average time to first byte read: 947ms
- average read time per runner: 3224ms
- average write time per runner: 2779ms
- p99 time to first byte: 4936ms
- p90 time to first byte: 926ms
- p50 time to first byte: 577ms

Remote (Through VIP | Seattle → IAD):
- Total Time to stream and read 50 audio files: 4840ms.
- average complete read and write: 4287ms
- average time to first byte read: 780ms
- average read time per runner: 3035ms
- average write time per runner: 2562ms
- p99 time to first byte: 4458ms
- p90 time to first byte: 857ms
- p50 time to first byte: 566ms


*1 - 118kb Audio File Streamed and Read Simultaneously from One Node in 4096 byte chunks*

Redis

*Notes:*
I used a 50ms polling interval to check for updates to the cache.

*Results:*
Local:
- Total Time to stream and read 1 audio files: 62ms.
- average complete read and write: 62ms
- average time to first byte read: 55ms
- average read time per runner: 61ms
- average write time per runner: 3ms
- p99 time to first byte: 55ms
- p90 time to first byte: 55ms
- p50 time to first byte: 55ms

Remote (Over SSH | Seattle → IAD):
- Total Time to stream and read 1 audio files: 394ms.
- average complete read and write: 394ms
- average time to first byte read: 57ms
- average read time per runner: 394ms
- average write time per runner: 342ms
- p99 time to first byte: 57ms
- p90 time to first byte: 57ms
- p50 time to first byte: 57ms

Remote (Through VIP | Seattle → IAD):
- Total Time to stream and read 1 audio files: 388ms.
- average complete read and write: 388ms
- average time to first byte read: 61ms
- average read time per runner: 388ms
- average write time per runner: 343ms
- p99 time to first byte: 61ms
- p90 time to first byte: 61ms
- p50 time to first byte: 61ms


Ignite

*Notes:*
None

*Results:*
Local:
- Total Time to stream and read 1 audio files: 32ms.
- average complete read and write: 32ms
- average time to first byte read: 2ms
- average read time per runner: 23ms
- average write time per runner: 11ms
- p99 time to first byte: 2ms
- p90 time to first byte: 2ms
- p50 time to first byte: 2ms

Remote (Over SSH | Seattle → IAD):
- Total Time to stream and read 1 audio files: 259ms.
- average complete read and write: 258ms
- average time to first byte read: 19ms
- average read time per runner: 232ms
- average write time per runner: 169ms
- p99 time to first byte: 19ms
- p90 time to first byte: 19ms
- p50 time to first byte: 19ms

Remote (Through VIP | Seattle → IAD):
- Total Time to stream and read 1 audio files: 203ms.
- average complete read and write: 203ms
- average time to first byte read: 20ms
- average read time per runner: 174ms
- average write time per runner: 93ms
- p99 time to first byte: 20ms
- p90 time to first byte: 20ms
- p50 time to first byte: 20ms
```

UPDATE:
To make more apparent what I'm trying to do:
I'm going to have 50+ million devices streaming audio.  The streams could be 100kb on average and 200k streams/minute at peak traffic.  I'm looking for a storage solution to accommodate that need.  I've been examining Bookkeeper, Kafka, Ignite, Cassandra, and Redis.  So far i've only benchmarked redis and ignite, but i'm surprised ignite is so slow.

Comment: could you please share your benchmark on github? it's difficult to say what is going on without a code.

Comment: https://github.com/Sahasrara/AudioStreamStoreDemo

Answer (score 2):

I reviewed your benchmark and made a couple runs locally. I was able to make it much faster:

1. 30 iteration isn't enough for JVM to warm up, on my laptop, it
   requires ~150 iterations. So I increased it to 300 iterations.
2. I moved cache creation out of the benchmark, I added it right after cache destroying.
3. Also, I moved out of benchmark ignite client creation, it's extremely expensive operation and in real life, you should reuse it.

Please take a look at my changes, I created a pull request:
https://github.com/Sahasrara/AudioStreamStoreDemo/pull/1/files

Comment: Thanks for investigating! A couple things I noticed:

1) since you no longer delete data, it's always available to read which would artificially reduce read time
2) we can't wait to flush the data until the stream finishes since that increases the critical time to first byte (and subsequent bytes) for our readers.

In our workload, we can either create a cache per device (+50 million) or a cache per audio file coming from those devices at random (200,000 per minute).  We'd have to create the utterances in an ad hoc manner in the latter case, but in the latter we can do it ahead of time.

Comment: you can use prefixes for keys to distinct data instead of different caches, I think it will be more efficient.

Comment: I don't see how we could do that while streaming unless there's some way it avoid a full table scan for filtering.

Answer (score 0):

- I don't think you should be creating a cache for every operation. This is a heavy operation with Ignite. What are your requirements for this?
- I can see how performance greatly improves for subsequent runs. Ignite is based on Java, which needs some time to warm-up.

Comment: All of these runs are the 30th iteration of the same test to allow for vm warm up so that shouldn't be an issue.  We have a cache group so it shouldn't' be taking 20mb per cache.  Ignite's client doesn't seem to handle threading well so it might not be a viable solution for us.

Comment: Cache creation and destruction doesn't thread because those events have to be propagated to the cluster via discovery mechanism. This is inherently costly.

Comment: We're going to have over 200,000 100k+ files cached in ~4k chunks every minute.  Would it be better to have a single cache with all that data in it?  TTL will be like 5 minutes.

Comment: Ah actually, that's not feasible.  We can't just do a scan query for to grab all the chunks while we stream, it would be inspecting every chunk streamed.  It's starting to sound like apache ignite isn't a good solution for streaming audio.

Comment: @Programmer9000 I don't see how you would go with scan query, provided that you likely depends on chunks' ordering. I'm at loss about what you're trying to accomplish here.

Comment: Updated my question with more context.  Let me know if you want me to add more.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely avoid creating a lot of caches.

- Use a cache group in order to share infrastructure between your caches.
- Keep a barrel of N caches and re-purpose them for a new files as time goes by, freeing them once file is no longer used. This will need keeping some accounting.
- Better yet, find a way to just use one cache, keep file identifier in composite cache key, keep track of what you have in cache.

Comment: Yeah that seems to be the way Ignite needs to be used.  That said, i'm already using a cache group.  You may be on to something, but as things stand even if I create the caches before hand (so that doesn't factor into the latency) it's quite a bit slower than Redis.  Lastly, I don't see how you could stream (which is a requirement) if you use composite keys like that.  Ignite would have to do a scan of the keys to filter.  Maybe it can do that efficiently though, I should give that a shot.

Comment: @Programmer9000 you can track keys in some kind of meta-cache or index cache.